# simple raw binary image file format

Tags: pgm, image-formats

I'm looking for a raw image file format as simplistic as PGM, but encoded in binary, so that I can write pixels in bursts.
I've searched over Wikipedia and Google and found none that didn't start to have complex headers and such.
Can anybody recommend me such a type of a file format?

Comment: Why can't you use PGM in binary ('P5') mode? See http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html

Comment: Sorry, I only saw P2. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way is to use the PGM format itself, in 'P5' (binary) mode. See [PGM format](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html#format) from the Netpbm documentation. Set `maxVal` to 255, to use the full 8 bit range.

This is probably the most common format for PGM, as it is extremely easy and fast to both read and write.